# geocraft V2 wordpress theme image upload error

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Hi am using geocraft to make city directory. on local environment image uploading is good but now i have moved files to subdomain of my website but here following error pops up when i try to upload image for a listing. Please help?

> function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1 in /home/msb3082j/public_html/mycity/citydirectory/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1320
>   http://mycity.jobzsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2"/>

I have tried to comment this line but still no use.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Please make sure your online php server version is compatible with the wordpress version you are uploading.